# Dynamically resize table view cell with image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have table view with image and labels. I want dynamic table cell height depends on both label text height and also image size. How can I achieve that?[image]

Currently I have given aspect ration to image view , but in output its taking same aspect ration and making image view's size fix. I want that whatever size of image will come, my image view should be made of that size. I have achieved that cell's dynamic height depend on label size but how to do same with image?
The concept of this question : [Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights) is working for label not for image

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)

Comment: @DánielNagy I have referred that and make my cell size dynamic according to label text but now I want that to resize according to image size, How can I do that for image?

Comment: you can get the image size, and add width and height constraints programmatically, then you can set both of them to the size of the image.

Answer (score 2):

If you are supporting iOS8 and above the below two line of code would work.

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 400 //Just give a maximum value
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension // This will take automatically.
```

Comment: this lines are working for label not for image size.